# Transformers: Cross Attention Tensor Shapes During Inference Mode

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

Having been trying to figure this out for a while.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69887535/question-about-tokens-used-in-transformer-decoder-attention-layers-during-infere) similar question but I don't think the proposed answer actually addresses the question.

During inference mode of an Encoder/Decoder Transformer, my understanding is we **don't** pre-pad the Decoder input sequence to match the Encoder sequence length (i.e. pass in `[start_id,]` and not `[start_id, pad_id, pad_id, ...]`)

I might be missing something but when I don't pre-pad, the attention mechanism cannot correctly compute the matrix multiplication because the Decoder input is of seq_length = 1 while the Encoder seq_length is > 1 (`T`).  For reference (see attached pic), I identified the tensor shapes during each step and you can see where the last matmul step cannot be performed given incompatible tensor shapes.

What am I missing?  Am I suppose to pre-pad the Decoder input?  Or do I truncate the Encoder output to match the Decoder length?  Something else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the order mixed up. For cross attention in an encoder/decoder transformer, the `query` comes from the decoder, and the `key`/`value` come from the decoder.

You can check this in the original [Attention Is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) paper. In section 3.2.3:

```
In "encoder-decoder attention" layers, the queries come from the previous
decoder layer, and the memory keys and values come from the output of the
encoder.
```

Say our decoder `query` is of size `(bs, sl_d, n)` and our `key`/`value` from the encoder is of size `(bs, sl_e, n)`.

When we compute attention, our attention map from the `query` and `key` will be of size `(bs, sl_d, sl_e)`. We then matmul the attention map with the `value` of size `(bs, sl_e, n)`, giving a result of size `(bs, sl_d, n)`, which matches the initial query size from the decoder.

I omitted the multi-head aspect for brevity, but the same applies there just with an extra axis and reshaping of the `d_model` dimension.

Comment: dang - even though I felt like I read that paper many times, I wish I had read 3.2.3 again :(  Thank you!